# Почему нельзя напрямую использовать суперглобальные массивы в $_GET, $_POST в php?

Tags: php

Иногда слышу, что прямое использование суперглобальных массивов (пример: `$_GET['value']`), таких как $_GET, $_POST и т.д. является плохим стилем.

Также и NetBeans говорит, что надо использовать фильтры типа `filter_input(INPUT_GET,'value')`.

Скажите, действительно ли это столь важно?

Comment: Используйте их как хотите. Если бы их нельзя было использовать, то разработчики их бы давно уже удалили :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, и это предопределяется самой сущностью глобальных переменных. К ним имеют доступ все компоненты программы, и, поэтому, если хотя бы один компонент меняет их, неверные данные получают и все остальные. Кроме того, это делает привязку к конкретным переменным, от которой в идеале лучше уйти - так, тот же роутер может понадобиться в консольном вызове (например, для создания ссылок в письмах), но если он будет ожидать при этом непустой `$_GET`, его нельзя будет запустить. Если же инициализировать этот роутер, предоставляя ему копию данных, а не доступ к `$_GET`, то его можно будет запускать откуда угодно и не бояться за то, что кто-то подменит `$_GET`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не понял, что вы подрузамеваете по роутером и что  он делает с `$_GET`

Comment: Роутер - компонент, отвечающий за нахождение того участка кода (контроллера), который должен обработать запрос (на самом деле там нужен будет `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, но не суть).

Answer (score 2):

Потому что любые глобальные переменные - зло, и влекут за собой непредвиденные побочные эффекты.

При построении большой системы, при декомпозиции, для повторного использования кода без лишней головной боли, для написания тестов, от глобальных переменных стоит избавиться.

Comment: Оно конечно может и так, только данные как-то получать надо. Пока что понял из предыдущего ответа, что отличие лишь в том что `$_GET['value']` можно переприсвоить, а `filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'value')` работает однозначно во всей программе независимо от массива `$_GET`

Answer (score 1):

Используйте сколько хотите, пока не начнете строить сложные архитектурные приложения с шаблонами проектирования и на базе MVC. Плохой стиль заключается в использовании глобальных переменных в целом.

То есть по хорошему в вашем коде должен быть один модуль, который получает и обрабатывает входные данные, а потом доступ к ним идет уже через этот модуль.