# PHP: избежать обращения к суперглобальному массиву напрямую в аргументе isset()

Tags: php

Как это обсуждалось в ответе на вопрос [Почему нельзя напрямую использовать суперглобальные массивы в $_GET, $_POST в php?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/450215/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B2-get-post-%D0%B2-ph), обращение напрямую к суперглобальным массивам - плохой тон.

Как можно переписать следующую строку, избегая обращения к суперглобальному массиву напрямую?

```
if (isset($_POST['title'])){...}
```

- Если мы напишем `if (isset(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'title')){...}`, то это будет ошибкой.
- Не пробовал, но могу предположить, что если мы напишем что-то вроде

  x = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'title');
  if (isset($x)){...};

то тоже будет ошибка, если `$_POST['title']` не существует, да и вообще такой код лишен адекватности, потому что сначала присваем значение переменной, затем проверяем существует ли она.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прямое обращение к глобальной переменной - это неправильно лишь потому, что невозможно контролировать изменения в ней, а вот обращение через **специальный класс** изолирующий ее от внешнего воздействия, который реализует методы доступа к данной переменной и ограничения на работу с ней - **это правильно.**

Правильные практики реализации подобных методов вы можете встретить в различных фреймворках, например есть класс Request и у него есть метод getPost($name), который по сути обращается к глобальному массиву **$_POST** и делает запрос в массиве по ключу $**name**, но данный метод не дает случайно сделать присвоение глобальной переменной из-за особенностей синтаксиса.

Самое простое решение - это реализовать класс со статическими методами, типа `Request::getPost($name)` или реализовать обычный класс и каждый раз его создавать, решение чуть лучше это доступ внутри контроллера к объекту request через this `$this->request->getPost($name)`, другое решение - это передача первым параметром в метод контроллера.

```
public function addAction(Request $request) {
    $request->getPost('name');
}
```

Реализаций может быть много. Точно сказать, какое лучше нельзя.

### Немного про фреймворки

Используйте фреймворк для разработки своего приложения, это снимет с вас головную боль по многим архитектурным решениям, если фреймворк подходит под вашу задачу и вы не пишите свой велосипед. У каждого личное предпочтения к фреймворкам и тут неправильно будет сказать, что лучше использовать, я бы рекомендовал начать с Lavarel, т.к. он достаточно простой в освоении и очень хорошо документирован.

У вас увидел filter_var, для фильтрации и валидации входящих данных рекомендую использовать библиотеки, типа Respect/Validation, в которой уже многое написано за Вас, а вам этим только остается пользоваться. Хотя во многих фреймворках уже реализована подобная возможность.

```
class Request {
   public static function getPost($name) {
       return (isset($_POST[$name])) ? $_POST[$name] : null;
   }  
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за время, потраченное на ответ и подробные объяснения! Вы бы не могли добавить пример с самым простым решением (класс со статическим методом), завершающийся кодом `if (isset($_POST['title'])){...} `, который будет работать, если подставить свои команды?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu Описал пример подобного класса :)

Comment: Хорошо, ещё раз спасибо за ответ! ^^